# H2 seems to misinterpret a valid join clause

Tags: sql, oracle, join, h2

Here is a simple test database schema. There is really nothing special about it. I am using **H2** version **1.4.200** in Oracle compatibility mode.

```
create table STUFF (
    ID number(19) generated by default as identity (start with 1 increment by 1),
    NAME varchar2(128) not null,
    constraint PK_STUFF primary key (ID),
    constraint BK_STUFF unique (NAME)
);

create table STUFF_DETAILS (
    ID number(19) generated by default as identity (start with 1 increment by 1),
    BLAH varchar2(128) not null,
    constraint PK_STUFF_DETAILS primary key (ID)
);

create table STUFF_MORE_DETAILS (
    ID number(19) generated by default as identity (start with 1 increment by 1),
    BLAH_BLAH varchar2(128) not null,
    constraint PK_STUFF_MORE_DETAILS primary key (ID)
);
```

Here's a view definition that works fine. No objection from H2.

```
create or replace view V_STUFF1
(
    ID,
    NAME,
    BLAH,
    BLAH_BLAH
)
as select
    S.ID,
    S.NAME,
    SD.BLAH,
    SMD.BLAH_BLAH
from
     STUFF S
     inner join STUFF_DETAILS SD
          inner join STUFF_MORE_DETAILS SMD
               on SD.ID = SMD.ID
          on S.ID = SD.ID
;
```

Here's a view definition that H2 chokes on with the following error message:

> Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Column "SD.ID" not found

```
create or replace view V_STUFF2
(
    ID,
    NAME,
    BLAH,
    BLAH_BLAH
)
as select
    S.ID,
    S.NAME,
    SD.BLAH,
    SMD.BLAH_BLAH
from
     STUFF S
     inner join STUFF_DETAILS SD
          left outer join STUFF_MORE_DETAILS SMD
               on SD.ID = SMD.ID
          on S.ID = SD.ID
;
```

**The only difference is the type of the join (left outer vs inner) but I fail to see a reason why this should make a difference with regards to SD.ID column visibility.**

To me this looks like a defect in H2 but before I raise an issue with H2 project I want to make sure I am not missing something obvious or doing something stupid.

PS: I am aware I can rewrite the view definition and make H2 accept it but ideally I would like to keep SQL code as close to the original as possible. It is a migration project.

PPS: Oracle (and DB2) have no trouble with both view definitions, so the issue appears H2 specific

Comment: The [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6__BABCGEDH) shows the `on` condition following immediately after the corresponding table reference or partition clause, where you would normally expect it, not at some arbitrary point later in the query. The parser seems to be somewhat forgiving but I'm not sure it's strictly valid.

Comment: The above query is valid, but I'd still recommend the regular JOIN ... ON ... JOIN ... ON, to make the code clearer for everyone involved.

Comment: Neither select is standard SQL, the parse is s join ... on s.id=sd.id & that sd is not in scope. The Oracle & MS manual are poor & don't justify this code or say what it means. What do  you think the queries mean & per what justification? DBMSs may accept such expressions with aliases out of scope, but don't say they do & don't say what they take them to mean. We can expect inner joins are interpreted as certain implicit/comma joins that introduce all table aliases before all conditions & hence put all condition table aliases in scope but that this isn't available for outer joins.

Comment: @jarlh What is your justification that either query is valid? See my comment above.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson Although the Oracle documentation says an ON follows a table name, that's more restrictive than standard SQL & what Oracle accepts, so presumably the Oracle grammar is just wrong & trying to describe standard SQL. Ditto for MS. The H2 manual correctly describes standard SQL nesting. On the other hand SD is out of scope in both queries but H2, Oracle & MS documentation don't address name scope or clearly give semantics. See my earlier comment re inner join likely being mapped to implicit join but not so for outer join.

Comment: @philipxy, ISO/IEC 9075-2:2016(E); <table reference> ::=
<table factor>
| <joined table>, <joined table> ::=
<cross join>
| <qualified join>
| <natural join>, 
<qualified join> ::=
{ <table reference> | <partitioned join table> }
[ <join type> ] JOIN
{ <table reference> | <partitioned join table> }
<join specification>

Comment: @philipxy, but it's quicker to use https://developer.mimer.com/sql-2016-validator/ to verify ISO/ANSI SQL syntax.

Comment: @jarlh I agree the text meets the syntax rules but what is the justification for SD being in scope in the final ON.

Comment: @philipxy, read it as "
from
     STUFF S
     inner join (STUFF_DETAILS SD
          left outer join STUFF_MORE_DETAILS SMD
               on SD.ID = SMD.ID)
          on S.ID = SD.ID".

Comment: @jarlh I agree with that parse but that doesn't address the name scoping.

Comment: @philipxy, the final ON has both its JOIN's left side table (S), and right side (SD, SMD) table in scope.

Comment: Anyway, this explains why I never write nested joins like this.

Answer (score 0):

A valid Oracle view/query must have each join predicate following the name/alias of the table that is being joined.

By reordering the `ON` clauses the query could take the form:

```
create or replace view V_STUFF2
(
    ID,
    NAME,
    BLAH,
    BLAH_BLAH
)
as select
    S.ID,
    S.NAME,
    SD.BLAH,
    SMD.BLAH_BLAH
from STUFF S
inner join STUFF_DETAILS SD on S.ID = SD.ID
left outer join STUFF_MORE_DETAILS SMD on SD.ID = SMD.ID
```

Comment: I am aware. I did not write those queries. The question is not whether there is a better way to do the same but why H2 chokes on `left outer join` and is perfectly fine with `inner join`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been acknowledged as a defect [1] by H2 developers and resolved with this PR [2]

[1] https://github.com/h2database/h2database/issues/3311

[2] https://github.com/h2database/h2database/pull/3312